# SoftKeyboard Doesn't adjust my screen, Tried windowSoftinputmode adjustPan & adjustResize

Tags: android, scrollview, android-softkeyboard

As the titles says all, But when i try putting my layout inside a  `ScrollView`,then it works, but the problem is i have a `Tablelayout` which also have a `ScrollView`, this means a vertical scroll inside a vertical ScrollView.

By putting my parent LinearLayout inside a `Scrollview`, my `TableLayout's` ScrollView does't work then.

How can i fix it.

```
<ScrollView>// Added to adjust my screen on softKeyboard
   <LinearLayout>

      <TableLayout>
      </TableLayout>

      <Scrolliew> // Is not working because of Parent ScrollView

          <TableLayout>
          </TableLayout>

      </ScrollView>

   </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Any Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have two ScrollView where it is the parent and also the child. How would android know which scrollview is the one being touched?

Comment: i know this, i have just mentioned it to elaborate my problem, whats the answer? how to resolve the problem i mentioned

Comment: take out one of the scrollview. you did not even mention what you are trying to achieve with the layout above, you just asked "how can i fix this". so what kind of help are you looking for? do you still want to keep the two scrollview?

Comment: i added the parent scrollview just beacuase it fixed my screen size on display of softkeyboard, otherwise i dont need that ScrollView.

Comment: can't you use RelativeLayout to achieve that?
but if you must use two scrollview, this might help

http://androidmaterial.blogspot.sg/2012/05/scrollview-inside-scrollview-scrolling.html